# Теперь(,) всегда волновавшее другие страны(,) единоличное доминирование Британии

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли в этом предложении запятые: "Теперь, всегда волновавшее другие страны, единоличное доминирование Британии на море стало перерастать в произвол."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неудачное стечение в начале "теперь" и "всегда". Без запятой - совсем плохо смотрится, но увы, это не основание её ставить.

А вот на каком основании хотите запятые поставить **вы** - это вопрос большой...

Если ради обособления причастного оборота - то не получится. Строго говоря, здесь нет причастного оборота. Есть этакое распространенное определение, стоящее к тому же перед определяемым словом.

"Единоличное доминирование" - вот тут отчасти согласен. Но только отчасти, определяется контекстом. 
Предлагаю компромисс.

***Всегда волновавшее другие страны единоличное доминирование Британии на море теперь стало перерастать в произвол.***

или

***"Единоличное доминирование Британии на море, всегда волновавшее другие страны, теперь стало перерастать в произвол.***

В обоих случаях пунктуация не вызывает ни сомнений, ни вопросов.

//===
Хотя смысл такой сентенции все равно не до конца понятен. Какая связь между волнением "других стран" и перерастанием в произвол?

В отношении "доминирование - в произвол". Выражение вызывает вопросы, это да, но запрещать его, разумеется, нет причин. Тут другое, верно ли это передает авторскую мысль? Такие сомнения порождает само поминание "других стран" в подобном контексте. Похоже, тут что-то не так то ли со стилистикой, то ли с риторикой.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужны. Причастный оборот не обособляется, если стоит перед определяемым словом.

*Теперь всегда волновавшее другие страны единоличное доминирование Британии на море стало перерастать в произвол.*